# Cordova (Android) Show Configuration page

Tags: android, cordova

As I do , from my APP , to show the settings page in Android GPS (only) ?
I want, if the GPS is off, to take the user directly to the configuration

Is it possible ? 
With some plugin?

Thanks

Comment: yes ,it's possible,you can use custom plugin to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
First download custom plugin form here https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello
```

Install plugin from local :- cordova plugin install LocalPathofDownloadedPlugin

and in JavaScript add following code:-

hello.greet("World", success, failure);

```
  var success = function(message) {
        alert(message);
    }

    var failure = function() {
        alert("Error calling Hello Plugin");
    }

    once you installed the above plugin you will have one java file (Hello.java) in src folder:-

    public class Hello extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("greet")) {

        //here you need to send intent

            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }
     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 1) {
           switch (requestCode) {
              case 1:
               break;
            }
         }  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Thse two plugins can do it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#switchtolocationsettings

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy